# Is PID cyclic? I cannot understand quotient ring is cyclic

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

In the textbook, it says
“If $R$ is a principal ideal domain and $r$ is an elt of $R$, then the quotient ring $R/(r)$ is a cyclic R-module.

I dont know why $R/(r)$ is cyclic.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cyclic here means that it's generated by one element as an $R$-module. Note that $1\in R$ generates $R$.

Answer (score 3):

I am just elaborating on Berci's comment.

Maybe you are confusing two different notions of being cyclic:

- A *cyclic group* is a group $G$, such there exists $g \in G$ with $G = \langle g \rangle$, i.e., all elements of $G$ are of the form $g^m$ for $m \in \mathbb Z$.
- A *cyclic $R$-module* (for a commutative unital ring $R$) is an $R$-module $M$ such that there exists an $m \in M$ with $M = \langle m \rangle_R$, i.e., $M$ is generated by $m$ as an $R$-module. By definition, $\langle m \rangle_R = \{rm \ | \ r \in R\}$.

Here, obviously, we are speaking about the notion of a cyclic $R$-module.
Now, as noted in the comments, $R/(r)$ is generated by $1 + (r)$ as an $R$-module. Here, one does not need to use that $R$ is a principal ideal domain (and it's hard to guess why you require this, because you don't provide much context).